Word for making duplicate data entries unique?
Suppose I have a dataset with duplicate IDs, which I wish to make unique.
As I understand it, to deduplicate them is to remove these duplicates in such a way that every remaining entry has a unique ID:
id | value      id | value
---+------  =>  ---+------
1  | one        1  | one
2  | two        2  | two
2  | TWO        3  | three
3  | three

But another way to resolve them might be to manipulate the IDs in such a way that every entry has a unique (generated) ID:
id | value      id | value
---+------  =>  ---+------
1  | one        1  | one
2  | two        2a | two
2  | TWO        2b | TWO
3  | three      3  | three

Is there standard terminology for this kind of operation?
